# How to refer to a specific instance of a reusable react-native component in another component?

Tags: javascript, scrollview, react-native

I'm new to react-native and I'm using react-native-flux-router.

I have the android hardware back button handler function in a component that is always mounted and all other components are pushed to the stack of the flux-router over that component.

I want to be able to scroll to the top of a scrollView inside one of the components that are pushed over the scenes stack.
I was wondering how can I reference the specific instance of that scrollView inside the component that has the backhandler function.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to scroll a scrollview in react-native? It has been asnwered before.

Comment: No, I want to scroll the scrollView from a component other than the one it's created in

Comment: When you render a component, you can have it's reference in a variable wherever you want. In global, for example. `<ScrollView ref={el => {global.scrollView=el}}>`. So `global.scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0)` now. Or try to write the question clearer.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want. Thanks  a lot .